# Can Borel Regularization be applied to all divergent summations? If no, why?

Tags: summation, divergent-series

So, I am currently trying to study the nature of divergent summations, and I often came upon their negative rational values in their regularizations. Such as this classic:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}$$

I was wondering, would it be possible to apply Borel Regularization to all summations. If Not, why?

Yours Sincerely,
Aster17

Comment: Unless you need it for your career as a mathematician (or perhaps a physicist) , my advice is to forget those regularizations completely. Of course , analytic continuations are useful and make completely sense. But the assignment of such a value to a divergent sum is strange , to say the least. I respect different opinions , but my opinion is that there is no merit coming from those assignments.

Comment: @Peter I don't really have a career haha. I am only curious about the assigning of such values to divergent sums and would like to know more. I complete respect your opinion and this question I pose is only one for satiating my own curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer regarding the Abel method.

The power series
$$A(z) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j z^j$$
is the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} - \frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ at $z_0 = 0$. Its radius of convergence equals 1.

The Abel summation method gives:
$$
Abel(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j) = \lim_{z \to 1^{-}} A(z) = \lim_{z \to 1^{-}} \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = + \infty.
$$

Comment: so this means different summation types don't give equal results? I am guessing there is no everything fit solution for summations now, is there?

Comment: The only "difference" they should have is that one cannot sum to a finite value (letting the result as "infinite") but the other can. It is ***intended*** to have a consistent framework for divergent summation, such that ***all accepted*** procedures should either give the same finite value, or stay with the result "cannot sum-still running to infinity".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, whether Konrad Knopp's book on series (including divergent series) has been translated to english (from german, from the 1920'ies if I recall this correctly). I like this book very much, he is much explanative, has many examples & exercises. *(But G.H.Hardy's book should be available everywhere in english spoken countries, however it is much more involved and likely not so easy to digest as the Knopp's book.)*

---

One thing what I've got from this, that the various known (and accepted!) methods of summation are of different "strength". So Cesaro-summation cannot sum geometric series (even when alternating), but Abel- and Euler-summation can (when signs of series are alternating; it has been designed for this task). But Euler-summation cannot sum factorial series ("hypergeometric") even when signs are alternating, but Borel can. And so on. There is a hierarchy of methods.

Even there are series, which can be summed by Cesaro, but not by Euler-summation, so the "strength" which I alluded to above is not a onedimensional aspect with a simple order.

---

It would be too much to explain, not well suited for Q&A on MSE, so I'd recommend you go further to collect introductory material before stepping more forward.

Comment: So, what you are basically trying to say is that there is no good, fit-all solution for summations now, is there? I can completely understand that actually, due to the fact that infinity on it's own is a very difficult concept to grasp, and trying to define a way of adding sums is even more difficult. There has been one thing I've been working on, and it seems to suggest that Borel regularization seems to be the way to go, but I'll take that with a grain of salt. If you could perhaps link me somewhere to this hierarchy, It would be helpful, and thank you for referring to the resources.